# Aurelia clear route history when switching to other app using setRoot

Tags: aurelia

The Aurelia router remembers which page I was last on, even after using setRoot() and it will redirect me to that page, even though I would want to land on the main app page again.

I'll try to explain it in a usecase.
I have two apps: `login` and `app`.
I login in `login` app and get redirected to `app`.
I navigate to `/securedPage` on `app` and then proceed to log out and get redirected to `login` again.
I login with another user on `login` and then I get **redirected to `app/securedPage`.**
I want to be and should be redirected to just `app`.

How do I clear the route history when switching between apps with setRoot()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wanted to help out, recently got this working and the suggestions above almost work, but they are missing some parts. In this thread, the creator of Aurelia (Eisenberg) repsonds with a suggestion:
https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/590

So to switch app root do the following:

```
    this.router.navigate('/', { replace: true, trigger: false });
    this.router.reset();
    this.router.deactivate();

    this.aurelia.setRoot('app');
```

In my case I could actually skip the reset and deactivate part and just do

```
    this.router.navigate('/', { replace: true, trigger: false });
```

However doing this.router.navigate('/') without the replace and trigger part caused problems especially when switching app root multiple times.

So make sure to add:

```
     ... { replace: true, trigger: false });
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the accepted answer now. Everything you said is true, I tested it as well.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but I had to add one more line after `setRoot`:
`this.deactivate()`. This is due to an issue that causes infinite reloads listed here: https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/132

Answer (score 2):

did you try

```
this.router.deactivate();
this.router.reset();
this.app.setRoot('app');
```

Comment: I did not, but I have a feeling this might do the trick. I might try it in the near future, thanks!

Comment: @Travo This is the correct solution and should be the accepted answer. Note that this needs to be called on the `AppRouter` (`deactivate()` does not exist on child routers and also this will not work correctly on those)

Comment: Cool beans. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

It is not pretty but this this did the trick for me:

```
router.navigate("/");
aurelia.setRoot("login")
```