# Aurelia - Switching between app roots with different route configurations

Tags: aurelia

### UPDATE

Could this issue have something to do with mu problem?
https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/400

---

I have an [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) application with two different roots, one for loggen in users, and another for anonymous users.

I have in other Aurelia apps implemented a chanaging of app root [based on the approach in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458274/how-to-switch-between-login-page-and-app-with-aurelia). This works very well when the `login` module is an "isolated" module with no additional routes, but I'm having a hard time getting it to work now.

#### index.js - root for anonymous users

```
import {inject, useView, Aurelia} from "aurelia-framework";
import AuthService from "./services/auth-service";

@useView("app.html")
@inject(AuthService)
export class Index {   
    constructor(authService) {
        this.auth = authService;
    }

    configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.title = "Super Secret Project";
        config.options.pushState = true;
        config.map([
            { route: ["","home"], moduleId: "home", nav: true, title: "Beginscherm" },
            { route: "over", moduleId: "about", nav: true, title: "Over" },
            { route: "inloggen", moduleId: "account/login", nav: false, title: "Inloggen" }
        ]);

        this.router = router;        
    }
}
```

#### ic-app.js - root for logged in users

```
import {useView, inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {RequestStatusService} from "./services/request-status-service";
import AuthService from "./services/auth-service";

@useView("app.html")
@inject(RequestStatusService, AuthService)
export class App {
    constructor(requestStatusService, authService) {
        this.requestStatusService = requestStatusService;
        this.auth = authService; // we use it to bind it to the nav-bar-top
    }

    configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.title = "Super Secret Project";
        config.options.pushState = true;
        config.map([
            { route: ["", "selecteer-school"], moduleId: "ic/select-school", nav: false, title: "Selecteer School" },
            { route: "dashboard", moduleId: "ic/dashboard", nav: true, title: "Beginscherm" },
        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

#### login code on auth-service.js

```
logIn(userData, rememberMe = false) {
    this.requestStatusService.isRequesting = true;
    return this.http
        .fetch("/token", { method: "POST", body: userData })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            if (response.access_token) {
                this.setAccessToken(response.access_token, response.userName, rememberMe);
                this.app.setRoot("ic-app");
            }
        });
}
```

and...

## log off code in auth-service.js

```
logOff() {
    AuthService.clearAccessToken();
    this.app.setRoot("index");
}
```

#### The Problem

Setting the different app roots works as expected, the problem is that *I would expect the new app root to automatically navigate to the **default route of the new root**, bit it tries to load the route it was on the moment `setRoot(...)` is called*.

To illustrate with an example,

1. I'm on the login page. `current route: /inloggen`
2. I click the log in button. `app.setRoot("ic-app") is called`
3. New root is loaded; `configureRouter` in ic-app.js is called, and then...
4. Console error: `Route not found: /inloggen`

The new root tries to stay in the same `/inloggen` route, but I would like it to load, or navigate to, the default route for that app root.
The same happens on logging out.

How can I force the app to navigate to the default route after changing root?

Answer (score 7):

I got this working great, I answered more about how to in this stackoverflow thread:

[Aurelia clear route history when switching to other app using setRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247052/aurelia-clear-route-history-when-switching-to-other-app-using-setroot/40170520#40170520)

Basically do the following

```
this.router.navigate('/', { replace: true, trigger: false });
this.router.reset();
this.router.deactivate();

this.aurelia.setRoot('app');
```

Answer (score 5):

In the router for anonymous users use the `mapUnknownRoutes`. Like this:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = "Super Secret Project";
    config.options.pushState = true;
    config.map([
        { route: ["","home"], moduleId: "home", nav: true, title: "Beginscherm" },
        { route: "over", moduleId: "about", nav: true, title: "Over" },
        { route: "inloggen", moduleId: "account/login", nav: false, title: "Inloggen" }
    ]);

     config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
       //check instruction.fragment
       //return moduleId
       return 'account/login'; //or home
     });

    this.router = router;        
}
```

Do the same strategy in the other router. Now, try to logout and login again, you will see the user will be redirected to his last screen.

**EDIT**

Another solution is redirecting to desired route after setting the rootComponent. For instance:

```
logOut() {
   this.aurelia.setRoot('./app')
    .then((aurelia) => {
      aurelia.root.viewModel.router.navigateToRoute('login');
    }); 
}
```

Here is a running example https://gist.run/?id=323b64c7424f7bec9bda02fe2778f7fc

Comment: How would you map a 404 page in this scenario?

Comment: returning the moduleId of the 404 page. Something like `return 'not-found';`. You can also inspect the instruction.fragment to decide which component should be rendered

Comment: This approach will work when logging in because there's only one login page, and therefore you'll always see the same `instruction.fragment` (`/inloggen` in my case).
The problem is that you can log off from anywhere in the application, so the `instruction.fragment` could be anything and I would never know when to `return "home"` or `return "/not-found"`

Comment: do you really need a "not-found" route for anonymous users? Well, in that case you could change the route after loading the component. `setRoot` returns a promise, so that should be possible. I'll try to write an example for you

Comment: @SergiPapaseit take a look at my edited answer and see this gist https://gist.run/?id=323b64c7424f7bec9bda02fe2778f7fc

Comment: See the update link from @SergiPapaseit, I've the same issue when I use your gist, the first time I click the logout button it does not work, second click the logout works

Comment: Are you still having issues with the gist?

Comment: @FabioLuz, the gist seems to be working properly now. What did you change?

Comment: @FabioLuz I tweaked your gist to make it a bit more explicit what's happening. Great sample!

Comment: @AsheyGran, @FabioLuz, `login.js` doesn't not define any routes, which is **a completely different scenario than my question**. If `login.js` (or in my case, `index.js` doesn't define any routes it works for me as well

Comment: @FabioLuz, that'd be nice of me to give you think, wouldn't it? ;-) https://gist.run/?id=00b8b3745a480fb04184e8440e8be8c5

Comment: @SergiPapaseit check app.js and authorized.js there are routes defined in both. The gist.run I just linked to makes this more explicit.

Comment: @AshleyGrant very nice ;-) !

Comment: @AshleyGrant, it stops working as soon as I remove the `config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction => {
        return './screen-1';
      });` from `authorized.js`

I want to be able to map a not-found route, so this won't cut it for me as it stands.

Comment: @SergiPapaseit see my edited answer, use that approach on both roots to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

My best practice would be to simply direct them there, and this is what I do in my applications:

```
login(username, password) {
  this.auth.login(username, password)
    .then(() => {
      this.aurelia.setRoot('app');
      location.hash = '#/';
    });
}
```

Comment: That's the workaround I have now, but that forces an application reload and I'd like to avoid that if at all possible. I can live with it, but I kind of hope there is a better way :)

Comment: application reload??

Comment: Well, I'm using pushState, so no `hash`es for me. So instead of `location.hash` I have to set `window.location.href`, which causes the whole site to reload

Comment: @SergiPapaseit Maybe use `history.replaceState(null, "", "/page");`.